# Laravel Relationships with 3 tables problem

Tags: laravel

I don't understand how to connect three tables in Laravel.

```
users> id, ...
groups> id, ...
group_user> id_group, id_user
```

I want to return all groups to me `auth()->user()->groups`.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the problem and what have you tried?

Comment: In user model 
return $this->belongsToMany(Group::class, GroupMember::class, 'id_user', 'id_group');
but returns an empty array

Comment: if you named your pivot fields `group_id` and `user_id` you would only need 1 argument to `belongsToMany`

Answer (score 0):

According to your explanation, group_user table holds many-to-many relationship between Group and User model. In case of a many-to-many relationship, you actually don't need a *GroupMember* model. This kind of table which holds many-to-many relationship is called pivot table. Read more from the [Official Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many)

The first argument is the Model you are relating to, the second one is the name of the pivot table, and third argument is the foreign key name of the model on which you are defining the relationship, while the fourth argument is the foreign key name of the model that you are joining to

User.php

```
class User
{
  public function groups()
  {
    return $this->belongsToMany(Group::class,'group_user','id_user','id_group');
  }
}
```